# Two UiAlertView messages with different button actions

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

I have been successfully created two alerts with four buttons. The first AlertView works great but the second alertView crashes my up. Here is my code:

```
-(void)showAlertWithTextField{
UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"info" message:@"Set Time For The Game." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"cancel", nil];
[alertView setTag:101];
alertView.alertViewStyle=UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] becomeFirstResponder];
[alertView show];
}

-(void)showexitAlertView
{
UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Timeout" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your final score is: %i", runningSore] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Restart" otherButtonTitles:@"Exit", nil];
[alertView setTag:102];
[alertView show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
UITextField *field = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
setTime = [field.text intValue];

NSLog(@"%d", setTime);
if (alertView.tag == 101 && buttonIndex == 0) {
    //if (buttonIndex == 0){
    NSLog(@"Ok");
    [self setTimer];
    [self countDownTimerPrepare];
    [self countDownTimerIntro];
    [self prepareForIntroAnimation];
    [self performIntroAnimation];
    [self categoriesList];
}
else if (buttonIndex == 1){
    NSLog(@"Cancel");
    ChooseViewController * controller = [[ChooseViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChooseViewController" bundle:nil];
    //controller.countdownLabel.text= score;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else if (alertView.tag==102 && buttonIndex == 0){


        NSLog(@"Restart");
    }
else if (buttonIndex == 1){
    NSLog(@"Exit");

}
}
```

Here is the drbugging message when i press a button from the second Alert view:

2013-09-11 17:12:06.106 Diplomatiki[2808:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'textFieldIndex (0) is outside of the bounds of the array of text fields'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c42012 0x1737e7e 0x1c41deb 0xa7f0f0 0xb5d0 0xa72020 0x174b705 0x682920 0x6828b8 0x743671 0x743bcf 0x742d38 0x6b233f 0x6b2552 0x6903aa 0x681cf8 0x1fc2df9 0x1fc2ad0 0x1bb7bf5 0x1bb7962 0x1be8bb6 0x1be7f44 0x1be7e1b 0x1fc17e3 0x1fc1668 0x67f65c 0x29fd 0x2925 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

I will apreciate any suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
   {
   UITextField *field = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
   setTime = [field.text intValue];
```

This is error, your second alertView doesn't contain any textField. As in documentation says:

*Retrieve a text field at an index - raises NSRangeException when textFieldIndex is out-of-bounds. 
   The field at index 0 will be the first text field (the single field or the login field), the field at index 1 will be the password field.*

This is a solution that should work

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  if (alertView.tag == 101 && buttonIndex == 0) {

   UITextField *field = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
   setTime = [field.text intValue];

   NSLog(@"%d", setTime);

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Crash is due to your second alert view don't have a textfield. But you are trying to access the textfield and it's value from the `clickedButtonAtIndex:`regardless which alerview is clicked.

Implement like: clickedButtonAtIndex

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag == 101)
    {
       UITextField *field = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
       setTime = [field.text intValue];
       NSLog(@"%d", setTime);

       if( buttonIndex == 0)
       {
          NSLog(@"Ok");
          [self setTimer];
          [self countDownTimerPrepare];
          [self countDownTimerIntro];
          [self prepareForIntroAnimation];
          [self performIntroAnimation];
          [self categoriesList];
       }
       else if (buttonIndex == 1)
       {
          NSLog(@"Cancel");
          ChooseViewController * controller = [[ChooseViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChooseViewController" bundle:nil];
         [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
       }
   }
  else if (alertView.tag==102)
  {
     if(buttonIndex == 0)
     {
        NSLog(@"Restart");
     }
     else if (buttonIndex == 1)
     {
       NSLog(@"Exit");
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Midhun i developed for hours and i can't think that was so easy. I read the message about the textField but you know some times mind stuck.

Comment: @axel: It happens sometimes, don't worry. Take a break :) All the best.

Comment: Midhun i want to completely fix these method and stop for today. Here is what i didn't expect. When i press the Exit button from the second alertView it works but on the Log i get "Cancel" like i press the cancel button from the first alertView. Is it normal or i miss something again?

Comment: @axel: Please check my answer, I edited it twice after posting it. The latest code piece fixes that issue also

Comment: One last thinking where is the correct place to put the alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton for the first alertview?

Comment: @axel: put that on this method `-(void)showAlertWithTextField` before calling the `show` method of alertview.

Answer (score 1):

Axel, the same problem as in previous case

```
- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{

  if (alertView.tag == 101){
   NSString *inputText = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
    if( [inputText length] >= 1 ){
       return YES;
     }
     else{
       return NO;
     }
   }else{
      return NO;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you riskpp. I really apreciate your help guys.